# Inverting y axis of datetimes in Python

Tags: python, datetime, matplotlib

I'm trying to produce a graph with datetime objects on the y axis, increasing from top to bottom. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5806656/4718223) suggests using invert_yaxis(), which throws 'ValueError: No sensible date limit could be found in the AutoDateLocator.' Setting ymin and ymax manually gives the same result. What am I missing?

Thanks in advance!

Edit: I'm using matplotlib 1.3.1 on Python 2.7.

```
import numpy
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import datetime

#set up x and y
dates = dates = [datetime.datetime(2015, 3, 12), datetime.datetime(2015, 3, 15), datetime.datetime(2015, 3, 17), datetime.datetime(2015, 3, 21), datetime.datetime(2015, 3, 9), datetime.datetime(2015, 3, 16)]
x = numpy.arange(0, len(dates), 1)

plt.figure()
plt.plot(x, dates)
plt.gca().invert_yaxis() #this is the bit that isn't working!
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can always set everything manually:

```
import numpy
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import datetime

#set up x and y
dates = [datetime.datetime(2015, 3, 12), datetime.datetime(2015, 3, 15), datetime.datetime(2015, 3, 17), datetime.datetime(2015, 3, 21), datetime.datetime(2015, 3, 9), datetime.datetime(2015, 3, 16)]
x = numpy.arange(0, len(dates), 1)
## create a time axis in seconds
tim = [(date-dates[0]).total_seconds() for date in dates]

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
ax.plot(x, tim)
# get the y-axis limits
ylim = ax.get_ylim()
# invert the y-axis
ax.set_ylim(ylim[::-1])

# create ticks and tick labels
nticks = 5
timarr = numpy.linspace(ylim[-1], ylim[0], nticks)
labels = [(dates[0]+datetime.timedelta(seconds=t)).strftime('%m/%d/%Y') for t in timarr]
ax.set_yticks(timarr)
ax.set_yticklabels(labels)

plt.show()
```

Comment: Thanks Julien, this does the trick :) I'd love to know why the (very much simpler) invert_yaxis doesn't seem to be working for me, though...

Comment: You're welcome ... Unfortunately, I don't know why invert_yaxis wasn't working. I didn't get the error when using it but it wasn't looking very pretty.

Comment: When I tried your code, I only saw 2 ticks both labeled 2015